# Swift iOS app to REST PHP API - What's the best practice for authentication?

Tags: php, ios, swift, restful-authentication

I'm in the process of building a iOS mobile application in Swift.  I have a RESTFUL API written in PHP which communicates between the mobile application and a database.  Everything is working perfectly.

The problem I've got is, I don't know what the best practice is for authentication.  I eventually want users to sign up for an account on my application, but I'd like to have the user enter login credentials as little as possible, so some kind of authentication/authorisation key would be preferred.

I see so many different recommendations when I've looked for an answer, yet can't seem to find a tutorial or set of tutorials that cover what I need.

Can you guys link me some sources on how I'd go about achieving the above?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Let me re-phrase.  What is best practice for authentication between a mobile app and RESTful API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Oauth2](https://oauth.net/2/) is great for this. Oauth2 is what powers the 'log in through Google' buttons you will see all over the web. Effectively, the user would log in to your API through the iOS app and the app would send a token to the server with every request.

See the [getting started page](https://oauth.net/getting-started/).

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'll look at Oauth2, read the official documentation and see how I get on.  Cheers!

Comment: Good luck! It can seem a bit back and forth between the client (app) and server (api) but it makes it a lot easier to implement multiple clients in the long run. There is most likely a library out there for iOS too. Are you using C# or Swift?

Comment: Thank you :)  Yeah, I think it's slightly more confusing throwing this third 'log in through Google' step into it, but I like to stay with best practices.  I'm using Swift, I was tempted to use the new Visual Studio Xamarin, but I've wrote in Swift for a while so decided to stick with it for now. Cheers!